# Is having a look and feel of another product copyright violation?

Tags: ui

Just wondering can you violate a Copyright/Patent by having a similar look and feel in your product which users are accustomed to by using other products?

As an example does Google Docs violate any laws by having a similar look and feel like Microsoft Word? They essentially use similar look and feel and even the button labels

Thanks,

Comment: Copyrights and patents are two different things entirely. Your example is not patent related so the question, as asked, is probably off topic.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I am not a lawyer please excuse the semantics. I simply wanted to know if having a similar look and feel of another product could cause any legal harm?

Comment: I'm not a lawyer either. Look and feel could be covered by design patents. Those are on topic for this site. I'd encourage you to read up on those and then post a more specific question.

Comment: @EricShain The "look and feel" of computer interfaces may also involve analysis under trademark law, i.e., "trade dress", where it contains distinctive features that create a likelihood of confusion as to its source, sponsorship or approval.

Comment: @Upnorth, Maybe a naive question but 'look and feel' of a coke can can certainly be their trade dress. But how can a user Interface be? A UI is made of single components, button/tables/labels etc. Just by arranging these components in a certain way how can one claim that they were the first to arrange components in such a way.  Its like the English alphabets already exist, if i make a word out of it, e.g. 'LOL ', then I have a legal protection for that word? I am not discussing a company's logo, that is unique but I come back to my original question does Google Docs UI violates Microsoft Word?

Comment: @user2745862 Being "first" isn't the test. Creating a distinctive association with the product or service is the key.  If you're intentionally recreating the distinctive combination of elements already associated with some other product or service, that could cause "legal harm". There is a lot of trade dress literature on the topic.  Whether any particular X violates Y  is something only a judge or  jury can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommending looking at two recent US cases in particular:

**[Tetris vs. Xio](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_case?case=18064882260025243346&q=863%20F.Supp.2d%20394&hl=en&as_sdt=2,5)**

[Case Summary (Willamette University Law)](https://willamette.edu/law/resources/journals/wlo/ip/2012/05/Tetris_Holding_LLC_v_Xio_Interactive_Inc.html) 
[Tetris Gets Permanent Injunction Against Xio (IP Watchdog](http://www.ipwatchdog.com/2013/02/12/tetris-gets-permanent-injunction-against-xio/id=34996/)

**[SpryFox vs. LolApps](http://digitalcommons.law.scu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1150&context=historical)**

[Recent Ruling in Triple Town/Yeti Town Game App Dispute Provides Cautionary Lessons for Both EA and Zynga (Forbes)](https://www.forbes.com/sites/ericgoldman/2012/09/27/recent-ruling-in-triple-townyeti-town-game-app-dispute-provides-cautionary-lessons-for-both-ea-and-zynga/#2c3995bcf922)

What is interesting about both cases is that the plaintiffs prevailed and that they were copyright (as opposed to patent) cases, seemingly moving copyright into patent-ish territory.

This is an especially pressing issue as eligibility of game and software patents has come into question, post-[Alice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Corp._v._CLS_Bank_International).

If game mechanics and software are deemed purely abstract and no longer eligible, it represents a gap in Intellectual Property protection that represents a violation of the "spirit of IP law."  *(i.e. the laws are very clear in regard to protecting creative work, but if that creative work is process-based, to which is to say, mechanical, the creator has no rights to that work?)*

Typically, [design patents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_patent) are filed for "look and feel" of a product, and distinct from copyright in that parts of the design can be mod-able or process-oriented (such as a clever positioning of a hidden drawer.)

However, patents do expire, and any process-based intellectual property (the domain of patents) that has been in the public domain, with minor caveats, is no longer protectable.  This may well be the case with Google docs in relation to MS Word.